# Search and return JSON file value from string of concatenated input values using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I am looking for some help to search a JSON file with a variable that is formed by concatenated 4 drop down list values and a static value together.
ie.

```
DL1   |  DL2 | DL3 |  DL4  |
1000  |  20  | 0.1 | 0.001 |
etc...   
            Minbudget       Concat val to grab Minbudget
10% (0.1):   20000            1000_20_0.1_0.001_0.1
20% (0.2):   30000            1000_20_0.1_0.001_0.2
etc...
```

I'm currently outputting the concatenation for the percentages just to see if that function worked (which it does). But what I need to do is use that as a search variable to grab the Minbudget value from the JSON file.

```
[
  {
    "concatenation": "200000_20_0.001_0.1",
    "audience": 200000,
    "cpic": 20,
    "bcr": 0.001,
    "control": 0.1,
    "Minbudget": 20000
  },
  {
    "concatenation": "200000_20_0.001_0.2",
    "audience": 200000,
    "cpic": 20,
    "bcr": 0.001,
    "control": 0.2,
    "Minbudget": 20000
  },
  {
    "concatenation": "200000_20_0.001_0.3",
    "audience": 200000,
    "cpic": 20,
    "bcr": 0.001,
    "control": 0.3,
    "Minbudget": 20000
  },
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ut9L1y7/1/)

- I grab the values from the JSON file to make up the lists, but they're in a de-duplicated array at the top.
- Do I need to reference getJSON again like I do?

I've written what I thought may be close to working, but any help would be appreciated!

```
 $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/annielawrencee/incrementalityform/master/power_calc.json", function(obj,tenperconcat) {
                                    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
                                      if (value.concatenation == tenperconcat ) {
                                        var tenperval = value.Minbudget;
                        $('#tenperbudget').val(tenperval)
                                      }
                                    });
                                  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you duplicate the final value in the 'concatenation', hence it doesn't match the value in the array of objects you retrieve.

You need to remove that final value, then loop through to pick up the 10-50% values of each combination.

Also note that you can store the retrieved object in a variable for later reference, as the AJAX request is always made as soon as the page loads. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var data;

  $.getJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/annielawrencee/incrementalityform/master/power_calc.json", function(obj) {
    data = obj;
    var dupaudience = [];
    var dupcpic = [];
    var dupbcr = [];
    var dupcontrol = [];

    $.each(obj, function(key, value) {
      if (dupaudience.indexOf(value.audience) == -1) {
        $("#audience").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.audience + "</option>");
        dupaudience.push(value.audience);
      }
      if (dupcpic.indexOf(value.cpic) == -1) {
        $("#cpic").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.cpic + "</option>");
        dupcpic.push(value.cpic);
      }

      if (dupbcr.indexOf(value.bcr) == -1) {
        $("#bcr").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.bcr + "</option>");
        dupbcr.push(value.bcr);
      }

      if (dupcontrol.indexOf(value.control) == -1) {
        $("#control").append("<option value=" + key + ">" + value.control + "</option>");
        dupcontrol.push(value.control);
      }
    });
  });

  var $outputs = $('.output');

  $('#audience, #cpic, #bcr, #control').on('change', function(obj) {
    var selectedAudience = $('#audience option:selected').text()
    var selectedCpic = $('#cpic option:selected').text()
    var selectedBcr = $('#bcr option:selected').text()
    var selectedControl = $('#control option:selected').text()

    var baseConcat = selectedAudience + "_" + selectedCpic + "_" + selectedBcr + "_0.";
    for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++) {
      var entities = data.filter(o => o.concatenation === baseConcat + i);
      if (entities.length != 1) {
        console.log('0.' + i + ' not found');
      } else {
        $outputs.eq(i - 1).val(entities[0].Minbudget);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="audience"></select>
<select id="cpic"></select>
<select id="bcr"></select>
<select id="control"></select>

<p>Control</p>
<p>10%: <input id="tenper" class="output" /></p>
<p><input class="tenperbudget" /></p>
<p>20%: <input id="twentyper" class="output" /></p>
<p>30%: <input id="thirtyper" class="output" /></p>
<p>40%: <input id="fortyper" class="output" /></p>
<p>50%: <input id="fiftyper" class="output" /></p>
```

Here's a fiddle example as the snippet seems to be struggling under the weight of data: https://jsfiddle.net/wxqe0Lpu/

Comment: Rory, you're a star! Thank you very much! Noticed the duplication just before I checked back on stack! Super to know about the Ajax, thank you again for your time :)

Comment: Just QQ, how easy is it to do error handling with the final step? (if concat+0.i isn't found in the json? can I use else in this iteration?

Comment: You can do that by checking the `length` of the entities found by `filter()`. I edited the example to give you a rough example